# best way to visualize counts for very large number of variables with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, lasso-regression

Im currently running LASSO models for particular set of data. There are hundreds of variables found in 17 different models and Im interested in seeing how many models a particular variable is found in. I thought the best way to do this in R would be to create a boxplot with the variable names on one axis and the number of times they show up on the other axis. However, due to the number of variables that exist, the graph is not very readable. This is how it currently looks:

[image: Number of LASSO Models Variables are Present In]

This is the code I wrote to create the plot:

```
dt1 %>% ggplot(aes(y=reorder(Variable_Name,-desc(n)),x=n)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",
               width=.5,color="black",fill="grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Count",breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)) + ylab(NULL)
```

So I would assume that a bar plot would not be the best way to present this information. Does anyone have any suggestion on what to use to better visualize the data? Would a Venn diagram work best in this scenario?

EDIT:

I used Timon 's suggestion and this is what I came up with. I still face some space issues but its definitely preferable to the previous attempt.
[image]

Comment: Ideas: (1) Forget the graph and present results in a table sorted by count. (2) Use a color-enhanced table. I would use ```rpivotTable``` to create a table with columns for Variable and Count with a Table Barchart or Heatmap added. (3) Something like a Treemap where one box lists all the variables with a Count of 5, another lists the variables with a Count of 4, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide the data, we cannot reproduce your plot or visualize the data differently. However, I could imagine that plotting the variable names as `geom_text` or `geom_label` could be useful (using jitter to avoid overlap). Alternatively, you may want to look at wordclouds, where the relative size of the variable names would represent the count of models in which they are included.

An example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(123)
data_test <- tibble(var_names = c(paste0("var", 1:50)),
                    count = c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 3), rep(5, 2)),
                    y_random = c(runif(50, min = -1, max = 1)))

data_test %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = count, y = y_random, label = var_names, color = as.factor(count))) +
  geom_text_repel(max.overlaps = 50) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "None",
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +  
  labs(x = "Count",
       y = "Variable name")
```

Output: [image]

Edit and another example:

As mentioned by Joel in the comments, a treemap could also be helpful - potentially better since it reduces white space on the plot. With my data above, this would look as follows (continuing with packages and data from above):

```
library(treemapify)
library(stringr)

# summarize data
data_collapse <- data_test %>% 
  group_by(count) %>% 
  summarize(n = n(),
            var_names = paste(var_names, collapse = ", "), .groups = "keep") %>% 
  ungroup()

# plot
data_collapse %>% 
  ggplot(aes(area = n, fill = as.factor(count), label = str_wrap(var_names))) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(place = "centre") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(fill = "Count")
```

Output:
[image]

When I summarize the data, I concatenate all variable labels for each count. In the plot, I use the `str_wrap()` function from the `stringr` package to automatically insert line breaks as appropriate.

Comment: This is actually a great suggestion. thank you!  I assume max.overlap is what ensures that the words are not touching each other?

Comment: Glad to hear that. ```geom_text_repel()``` from the `ggrepel` package already ensures that labels don't overlap, but if there is not enough space it may drop some observations/labels. This is why I set `max.overlap = 50`, but it will depend on your distribution of the data whether this is necessary (set it to `Inf` to always show all labels) - see also [examples of ggrepel here](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html).